# Ordenar lista por dos campos alfanumericos

Tags: c#, ordenamiento

Tengo una lista alfanumerica con varios campos los cuales los muestro en una tabla html y se mira asi.

```
//tabla HTML
|Numero Interior|Manzana|Lote|Numero Exterior|
|15             |10     |10  |0              |
|13             |5      |5   |0              |
|12             |1      |1   |0              |
|17             |1      |2   |0              |
|13             |20     |3   |0              |
|13             |1      |3   |0              |
|1233           |5A     |2   |0              |
|1233           |5B     |2   |0              |
|1233           |1      |1A3 |0              |
|1233           |1      |2B2 |0              |
```

Lo que necesito es ordenarlo por Manzana y lote de manera decendente y que tome en cuenta las que tiene letras. Cabe señalar que los campos obviamente son de tipo string y al momento de ordenarlos usando

```
MiLista = MiLista.Orderby(x => x.Manzana).ThenBy(y => y.Lote).ToList();
```

Los ordena pero cuando hay algun numero, por ejemplo del 1 al 10 en la manzana
me los ordena:

```
//tabla HTML
|Numero Interior|Manzana|Lote|Numero Exterior|
|15             |1      |1A3 |0              |
|13             |1      |2B2 |0              |
|12             |1      |1   |0              |
|17             |1      |2   |0              |
|13             |1      |3   |0              |
|13             |10     |10  |0              |
|1233           |20     |1   |0              |
|1233           |5A     |2   |0              |
|1233           |5B     |2   |0              |
|1233           |5      |1   |0              |
```

Alguna sugerencia para poder ordenarlos en base a manzana y lote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar `PadLeft` para rellenar durante el sort:

```
  MiLista = MiLista.Orderby(x => x.Manzana.PadLeft(2,'0')).ThenOrderBy(y => y.Lote.PadLeft(3,'0')).ToList()
```

Comment: Funciono, Gracias